# ASP.NET StackedBar Chart Unexpected Result

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, charts, mschart

I created an asp.net StackedBar chart with values coming runtime from the database.

Here is how it looks :

[image]

Why do my colors not change according to the values on the chart ?

So value 56 should show more red color whereas values 1 should show less red color ? Right now, allthough the values are all different, the width of the colors are all same which does not give the right effect of the graph ?

Code used :

```
Dim chart As New Chart
                chart.ID = DtDistinct.Rows(I)("CourseSisID")

                Dim chartareas As New ChartArea
                chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartareas)

                ' chart.DataBindTable(DtRecords.DefaultView)

                chart.DataBindCrossTable(DtRecords.DefaultView, "Outcomescore", "ShortName", "Outcomescore", "Label=RecordsPerGroup")
                chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Interval = 1
                chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = True
                chart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None
                chart.PaletteCustomColors = New Color() {ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#DF5B59"), ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E0D773 "), ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#8AAC53"), ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#6A843F")}

                chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
                chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = False

                Dim charttitle As New Title
                charttitle.Text = DtDistinct.Rows(I)("CourseSisID")
                chart.Titles.Add(charttitle)

                For Each cs As Series In chart.Series
                    cs.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar
                Next
                pnlcharts.Controls.Add(chart)
```

Data :

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Dee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
chart.DataBindCrossTable(DtRecords.DefaultView, "Outcomescore", "ShortName", "Outcomescore", "Label=RecordsPerGroup");
```

with this:

```
chart.DataBindCrossTable(DtRecords.DefaultView, "OutcomeScore", "ShortName", "RecordsPerGroup", "Label=RecordsPerGroup");
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This worked. I had been trying this from so long and did not know a small thing could make it work!!!!

Comment: Just so you know, the way we say _thank you_ around here is by **Up Voting**...:O)

Comment: I upvoted! But it tells me that votes with reputation of less than 15 are not publicly displayed.

Comment: I had an another question which I posted as a new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211145/asp-net-stackedcolumn-chart-axis-trouble                                                                                                             It would be great if you could point my error in that as well ? Thank you!!!

Comment: In case no one else answers it before, I'll look at it a little later, thanks.